# Makefile overwriting itself

Tags: c, makefile

I have written a simple, semi-generic, `Makefile` to compile a simple C project, however, it randomly overwrites itself. This is the output of calling `make`:

```
clang  -g -O0 -march=native -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -c appley.c -o Makefile.o
clang   Makefile.o   -o Makefile
rm Makefile.o
Makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

This is the makefile:

```
CC      ?= gcc
DEBUG   ?= -g -O0 -march=native

CFLAGS  := $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic
LDFLAGS := $(LDFLAGS)
LDLIBS  := $(LDLIBS)

SRC     := appley.c
OBJ     := $(SRC:.c=.o)
SYM     := $(SRC:.c=.o.dSYM)
BIN     := appley

PREFIX  ?= /usr/local
BINDIR  := $(PREFIX)/bin

.PHONY: clean all

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN)

%.o: $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

install: $(BIN)
    install -d $(BINDIR)
    install $(BIN) $(BINDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) $(BIN)
```

How can `$@` become `Makefile.o`? And also, how can `$(BIN)` become `Makefile`? 
I believe it's the wildcard, since without it seems to work fine.

**Edit:** It's not the wildcard, it's saving the source file in VIM in another TMUX pane. Compiling after that scrambles up the makefile. I'm officially confused.

Comment: The makefile you provide has no error and cannot produce the output you've shown here.  So, clearly when you "_stripped out not necessary parts_" you actually removed the part of the makefile which is causing your error... this means we can't help you solve your problem.

Comment: @MadScientist No, I can actually reproduce it with this makefile. But you are correct, the answer below is not the whole truth,  I overlooked something

Comment: Added full makefile.

Comment: clang truncated his Makefile when it tried to use it as an output.

Comment: The "warning" is produced because the makefile looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Kw8i9FCH Which is the binary produced by `clang`.

Comment: Hm.  Yes, I see the problem.  It's clearly the `%.o : $(SRC)` rule.  The reason why is obscure but it goes like this: before make tries to build any targets it tries to rebuild the makefile, so it's looking for a rule to build `Makefile`.  There is no explicit rule, so it looks for an implicit rule.  Make has an implicit rule that can build any `foo` from `foo.o`.  There's no `foo.o`, but you've defined a pattern rule that can build any `%.o` from `appley.c` (`$(SRC)`).  So to rebuild `Makefile` make builds `Makefile.o` from `appley.c` then builds `Makefile` from `Makefile.o`.

Comment: Then make re-execs itself with the new `Makefile` but this has been overwritten by your program you were trying to build, and so make fails.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation @MadScientist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern rules usually have a % on both sides. Try replacing this,

```
%.o: $(SRC)
```

with this,

```
%.o: %.c
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the error. And I also now when it happened, it happened when I compiled the binary, changed the source, and then recompiled (which only compiles the detected changes).

Comment: Weird things happen in the original example, its not even deterministic. I put the original contents in `temp.mk`, then ran this wrapper script as `test.sh`, http://pastebin.com/BVNumq1f , and maybe 1 in 10 times it works as expected, the other 9 times it overwrites the Makefile. Output: http://pastebin.com/6CZ9ATUv

Comment: Btw I am assuming @Leandros is on OSX because `clang`. I tested on Linux, but same problem.

Comment: I'm indeed on OS X, and I was using the make supplied by Xcode, which is not a GNU make. It's also quite old, it's version 3.81, current stable is 4.1.